# getting strange ip when using Request.servervariables c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ip

My web application runs on a local IIS server. When calling the api of my web app
using fiddler i get a strange client ip adress.

```
public static class HttpRequestMessageHelper
{
    public static string GetClientIpAddress(this HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        string ip = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
        {
            ip = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
            {
                return "Unknown IP-Adress";
            }
        }
        return ip;
    }
}
```

I am using this extension method for obtaining the ip.
The ip i am getting looks like this: "fe80::745a:d3fa:db2c:7b94%11"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an IPv6 address:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6

As the world is running of IPv4 addresses (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) the new standard is to bring in **a lot** more addresses.

Sadly they're not as easy to remember, so DNS lookups will be vital IMHO.

You can check you adaptor settings / `ipconfig` and  / or your DHCP server (local router perhaps?) and see, chances are you being issued IPv6 addresses.

Comment: Thats it, fiddler is using IPv6 by default if available! Thx